# How do I change the encoding of my files?

Tags: input-encodings

Back in the old days, before I left the hallowed shores of my native country, I didn't much care what encoding my files were in.  ASCII was enough for my great-great grandfather so it was enough for me.  Now I live in the land of my great-great-...-great grandfathers who have a slightly mangled alphabet and ASCII no longer suffices.  That would be fine if it were just me: I've learned to love UTF-8 and have even embraced `xelatex`.  But sometimes I get sent documents in weird encodings, and sometimes I want to resurrect some old document, maybe to include a section in a new document, so from time to time I find myself wanting to change the encoding of a document.

So: how do I do that?  (Included subquestion: how do I determine the encoding of a file?)

**Notes:**

1. I realise that this is only tangentially related to TeX and friends, so am fully prepared to be told to look elsewhere, but I think that this is quite common and especially (due to the fact that it seems one has to be super-aware of encodings with TeX) important for TeXers.
2. I don't have a *specific* example file in mind here, this is a "generic" question hoping to build a useful resource.  So please answer in as full generality *as you can* and where you need to place restrictions, please make them clear.  In particular, this will almost certainly have different answers depending on the OS.
3. On the other hand, if you *do* know a super-snazzy-wizzy method that works just brilliantly when using Emacs at midnight with a full moon, then please do post it - just be sure to include whether you are assuming the *strong* lycanthropic principle or only the weak one.
4. In light of those last two, I'd be happy for this to be CW with one answer gathering together all the techniques in a sensible grouping.
5. If this question *doesn't* get closed and does work as I intend, these notes should probably be removed so as not to distract from the usefulness of the answers (and because we probably *don't* want TeX-SX to be the number one hit for the "strong lycanthropic principle").

Comment: @Andrew: Are you looking for a single-file or a 'job lot' approach? A number of editors can read and write different encodings, so for simple cases it's just a question of your editor. On the other hand, bulk changes sound like a question for SuperUser.

Comment: @Joseph: Hadn't thought about that.  The scenario I most encounter is "single file".  I think that if I had a "job lot" then I'd figure it out once and for all and write a shell script to do it for me.  But this happens just infrequently enough that I never remember from one occurrence to the next how to do it.  (In case it's not clear, I'm also deliberately playing "new-users' advocate" in that I could probably figure it out for myself but I think that this would be a really useful thing to have on this site.)

Comment: I think that Joseph is right. Propably any decent editor has the capability to change the encoding of a file. Usually moving from ASCI to utf-8 is not a problem. The other way can lead to data loss (data corruption actually). Nowadays, I think that you should always work with Utf-8 regardless of the files contents.

Comment: @pmav99: I agree that one _should_, and I would tend to convert from "X" to UTF-8 whenever possible.  Sometimes, though, I need to send files in particular encodings to people who are ... how shall I put it? ... less aware of encoding issues than myself.  I also agree with the first sentence, but then apparently Emacs has the ability to change the universe so that my program is written already, but somehow `M-x quantum butterfly` doesn't work for me, so having actual instructions for the clueless (ie me) would (I think) be a useful resource for this site.

Comment: I was going to mention `file` (which mostly works), but it failed to detect the encoding of a CP1251 text :-) For conversion, however, `iconv` is perfectly suited.

Comment: @Andrew, I don't disagree with you. I think that this is a useful question. Perhaps not directly related to TeX but afterall TeX is about editing text files... so working with files and knowing about their encodings is something that you'll have to learn at some point (though you usually learn it the hard way).

Comment: Not a literal answer to your question, and not what I would normally recommend, but: if you use `selinput`, your file should work regardless of encoding.

Answer (score 17):

Regarding Emacs: Sometimes I stumble upon a *tex-file encoded with latin-1 or latin-9, but the second line usually is `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}`. In Emacs, I delete this line and add via C-c C-m a new `\usepackage`, wait until Emacs finished looking which packages are installed and type `inputenc`. Emacs then suggests `latin-1`, I type `utf-8` and Emacs asks, whether the whole buffer should be encoded with utf-8. YES! And Emacs recodes my file.

EDIT: According to comments, it seems useful to add: this is an AUCTeX feature. AUCTeX is a powerful Emacs package which adds much comfort when writing *.tex files.

Otherwise look for the manpage of `recode`.

Alexander

Comment: Looks extremely useful!  Are you using any particular Emacs library for TeX files?

Comment: Uhm, you know what AUCTeX is? http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/ You need that. A.

Comment: Keks, that this is a facility of AUCTeX should be added to your answer.  That's the sort of detail that's quite important.  Not _every_ user of Emacs uses AUCTeX (me, for example!).

Comment: @KeksDose Please if I add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and I hope to write for example `Gabès` it doen't compilate. However with `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` it complilates well. I use wenedit 5.6. Where is the problem? And how can I fix it? Thank you.

Comment: @Schüler Ask a new question with a minimal working example!

Comment: You can do this without AucTeX. Just do `M-x revert-buffer-with-coding-system` and select the encoding you wish the current buffer (file) to have.

Comment: @KeksDose Ok this is my new question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/462963/problem-with-accents-and-inputenc

Answer (score 15):

I recently have had some issues with the encodings of different files (`*.bbl` and `*.tex` for instance), resulting in missing glyphs or funny combinations in place of accented letters.

A solution that worked for me, in Linux (Ubuntu 10.04 distribution), was using the `iconv` program:

```
iconv -f source_encoding -t dest_encoding inputfile.tex > outputfile.tex
```

Comment: `iconv` is also available for Windows via [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/)

Answer (score 9):

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) is a very nice editor for Windows, it shows the current encoding and can convert the encoding to a different one. I use `UTF-8 without BOM` and the files worked well in all other editors afterwards.
[image: Notepad++ GUI for encoding conversion]

Answer (score 8):

Changing the encoding of a file in emacs is easy, at least in GNU emacs at or beyond version 23, I think. First, visit the file in an emacs buffer. If emacs does not automatically visit the file with its current encoding, close the buffer, then type `C-x C-m c` to specify the file's current coding system, then open the file (using `C-x C-f` for example). Second, change the encoding by typing `C-x C-m f` to specify the new coding system. When you save the file, the new coding system is used.

The second issue is how to ensure emacs picks the right coding system next time you visit the file. For LaTeX files, it is usually not a problem, since latex mode looks at the `\usepackage[…]{inputenc}` to figure it out. There is a more general mechanism, but discussing that is outside the scope of this site, I think.

Comment: Or just do `M-x revert-buffer-with-coding-system`, which is equivalent to what you suggest (afaik).

Answer (score 7):

For single-file changes, I stick with my editor-of-choice (TeXworks), which can load and save a variety of encodings. The standard setting is UTF-8, but it will work with lots of others. (Auto-detection is based purely on the file itself, with no checking for inputenc or similar, so it may be that Emacs is a better choice in some cases.)

Comment: I think that inputenc is not a full proof way to detect the file's encoding. You can write whatever you want in the preamble and still save it in a different encoding. Then if you send it to someone else it will be decoded to gibberish. Propably a comment at the start of the file is the way to go (python like)

Answer (score 6):

`iconv` is also available for Mac OSX (besides Linux) although I don't know if it came with the OS or if I installed it with the huge MacTex-Works package.

I had to figure out to which encoding I accidentally saved my file. So I had to try out different encoding conversions.

In the terminal, this listed all the encodings available

```
iconv -l
```

This way I tried out one possible conversion after the other until my special characters (ü, ß, ...) were displayed correctly in the terminal

```
iconv -f MAC -t UTF-8 test.tex
iconv -f LATIN1 -t UTF-8 test.tex
```

This converted from UTF-8-MAC to UTF-8:

```
iconv -f UTF-8-MAC -t UTF-8 test.tex > test_UTF-8-MAC_UTF-8.tex
```

Comment: Useful to know.  Checking my Mac system, I find `iconv` in `/usr/bin/iconv`.  The date of creation matches that of other binaries that I would expect to be there by default (such as `gzip` and `ssh`) so I would say it is almost certain that `iconv` comes with the OS.

Answer (score 4):

There was also a GUI program called Charco that was available for Mac OS X, GNU/Linux and Windows:

https://web.archive.org/web/20171029181036/http://www.marblesoftware.com:80/Marble_Software/Charco.html

Answer (score 3):

I can see that no-one mentioned the `konwert` utility (it is certainly present in ubuntu repositories).  It has a lot of "filters" (for different encodings), can recognize some of them, nad has a lot of nice options, like removing trailing spaces, recoding cr/lf/crlf standards, escaping # $ % & \ ^ _ { | } ~ to TeX, rot13-ing the file and even more.