# Extended ASCII characters in LaTeX document

Tags: unicode, input-encodings

I need to display a few extended ASCII characters and this is what I have coded so far.

```
\documentclass[a4paper , 12pt]{report}


\usepackage[mathletters]{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
   $½·®½´»ò Í«°°±-» §±«$
\end{document}
```

The error message that I've got is

```
Package utf8x Error: Character189appearedalone.
```

This error message appears for each extended ASCII character between the two `$` marks.

Could someone please help me out?

It is not necessary to use math mode. Non math mode suggestions will do as well.

Comment: Well, why would you want these characters in math mode in the first place?

Comment: i just tested them out in math mode to see whether it works, i do not need them in math mode. These characters appear along with other normal ascii characters

Answer (score 8):

You should avoid using the [`ucs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/unicode) package as it hasn't been maintained for a long time - see the question [utf8x vs. utf8 (inputenc)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13067/3323). Instead you can use T1-encoded fonts and `textcomp`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
   ½·®½´»ò Í«°°±-» §±«
\end{document}
```

(Don't forget to save the file encoded in UTF-8.)

---

If you want to keep your current file encoding, ANSI, you should pass the option `ansinew` instead of `utf8` to `inputenc`. However, the plus-minus sign (±) doesn't seem to be considered in this encoding by default, so you have to take care of that yourself, like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textplusminus}{TS1}{'261}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\textplusminus}{TS1}
\DeclareInputText{177}{\textplusminus}
\begin{document}
   ½·®½´»ò Í«°°±-» §±«
\end{document}
```

Comment: nope it doesnt work, i get Package inputenc Error: keyboard character used is undefined.

Comment: @KiloWatt I suspect your file isn't encoded in UTF-8, but e.g. in ANSI - check the settings of your editor and re-encode the input file appropriately.

Comment: isnt there another method, i find it difficult to convert all my tex files to utf-8

Comment: @KiloWatt What input encoding are you using at the moment?

Comment: @KiloWatt BTW: The question [How do I change the encoding of my files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19427/3323) might be helpful.

Comment: i am using ansi, isnt there a method around this? Isnt there a special tag to insert these characters. They are all ascii so a ANSI file is be able to store them.

Comment: @KiloWatt See my updated answer.

Comment: nope it doesnt work either. It says use mathaccents for accents in math mode and when i removed the $ mark it gives missing $ inserted,  What can i do now ?

Comment: @KiloWatt It sounds as if you're now using the second solution (`inputenc` option `ansinew`) with an *UTF-8* encoded file. Please recheck the encoding of your input file.

Answer (score 0):

You should save the *.tex file in UTF8 (not in ANSI).
[image: coding of tex-file]