# General error caused by accent or apostrophe?

Tags: errors

I wrote the thesis in Microsoft Word and now I want do the same on LaTeX. I'm using TeXStudio.
I already wrote the introduction without problem and now I was going to write the first chapter but when I mount the code it gave me an error that I can't understand.

```
Missing $ inserted. ...na patologia unicamente femminile, ma puÃ²
Extra }, or forgotten $. ...na patologia unicamente femminile, ma puÃ²
Please use \mathaccent for accents in math mode. ...iccome anch egli possiede piccole quantitÃ
You can't use `\spacefactor' in math mode. ...iccome anch egli possiede piccole quantitÃ
Please use \mathaccent for accents in math mode. ...asi della vita, maschi e femmine hanno piÃ
You can't use `\spacefactor' in math mode. ...asi della vita, maschi e femmine hanno piÃ
Please use \mathaccent for accents in math mode. ...mmine hanno piÃ¹ o meno la stessa quantitÃ
You can't use `\spacefactor' in math mode. ...mmine hanno piÃ¹ o meno la stessa quantitÃ
Please use \mathaccent for accents in math mode. ...tuazione cambia con l'arrivo della pubertÃ
You can't use `\spacefactor' in math mode. ...tuazione cambia con l'arrivo della pubertÃ
Missing $ inserted.
Missing $ inserted. ... alla ricerca di noduli. Questo esame puÃ²
Extra }, or forgotten $. ... alla ricerca di noduli. Questo esame puÃ²
Please use \mathaccent for accents in math mode. ...a paziente (tipicamente a partire dall'etÃ
You can't use `\spacefactor' in math mode. ...a paziente (tipicamente a partire dall'etÃ
Please use \mathaccent for accents in math mode. ...questi sistemi di imaging, il medico potrÃ
You can't use `\spacefactor' in math mode. ...questi sistemi di imaging, il medico potrÃ
Please use \mathaccent for accents in math mode. ...ma di imaging non sia possibile capirlo, Ã
You can't use `\spacefactor' in math mode. ...ma di imaging non sia possibile capirlo, Ã
Please use \mathaccent for accents in math mode. ...a di imaging non sia possibile capirlo, Ã¨
Missing { inserted. ...a di imaging non sia possibile capirlo, Ã¨
You can't use `\spacefactor' in math mode. ...a di imaging non sia possibile capirlo, Ã¨
Please use \mathaccent for accents in math mode. ...ca di un campione di tessuto sospetto cosÃ
You can't use `\spacefactor' in math mode. ...ca di un campione di tessuto sospetto cosÃ
Missing $ inserted.
Missing } inserted.
destination with the same identifier (name{page.i}) has been already used, duplicate ignored<to be read again> \relax l.22 \item D eve essere attendibile: il test deve avere un buon rapporto tra...
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
destination with the same identifier (name{page.ii}) has been already used, duplicate ignored<to be read again> \relax l.234 [2] (capitolo1.texpdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same ident
Command \~ invalid in math mode
Command \~ invalid in math mode
Command \~ invalid in math mode
Command \~ invalid in math mode
Overfull \hbox (1721.6554pt too wide) in paragraph
Command \~ invalid in math mode
Command \~ invalid in math mode
Command \~ invalid in math mode
Command \" invalid in math mode
Command \~ invalid in math mode
Overfull \hbox (304.8004pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (1416.86214pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (703.07468pt too wide) in paragraph
File `tesi.out' has changed.
name{chapter*.4} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
```

If I erase the first chapter, everything runs correctly. I also copyed the introduction to replace the first chapter and the errors appears again (but there is no problem with the introduction at the top of the document).
This is my code

```
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  % Usare una versione di LaTeX con sillabazione italiana %
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,english,italian]{book}

% Usare "oneside" invece di "twoside"
% nelle bozze, per risparmiare carta:
% "twoside" produce diverse pagine bianche
% alla fine dei capitoli.

                    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
                    %         inputenc             %
                    %  Usare l'opzione "latin1"    %
                    %  se si vogliono scrivere     %
                    %  lettere accentate da        %
                    %  tastiera su Windows o Unix  %
                    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

       %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
       %                  babel                     %
       % Pacchetto tipico per una tesi in italiano. %
       %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\usepackage{babel}


   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   % Se nella tesi si inseriscono dei passi in un'altra       %
   % lingua (inglese, per fissare le idee), si puo' istruire  %
   % il TeX di sillabare quella parte di testo con le regole  %
   % inglesi, invece che italiane. A questo scopo basta       %
   % scrivere                                                 %
   %                                                          %
   %    \documentclass[...,english,italian,...]{...}          %
   %                                                          %
   % al posto di \documentclass[...,italian,...],             %
   % dopodiche' la sillabazione sara' italiana fintanto che   %
   % non si incontra il comando \selectlanguage{english}.     %
   % Per tornare all'italiano si scrive                       %
   % \selectlanguage{italian}                                 %
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{uniudtesi}

% Col pacchetto tocbibind compariranno nell'indice anche
% la bibliografia ed eventualmente l'indice analitico
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

% Il pacchetto indentfirst abolisce la fastidiosa convenzione
% anglosassone di fa cominciare la prima riga di un
% capitolo o sezione a margine sinistro, senza rientro:
\usepackage{indentfirst}

% \usepackage{graphicx} % gia' caricato da uniudtesi
\graphicspath{{./figure/}}
%\usepackage{epstopdf}


       %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
       % Pacchetti tipici per una tesi di matematica  %
       %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{latexsym}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                    graphicx                         %
%                                                     %
%   Uno dei pacchetti per l'inserzione di figure      %
%   in formato eps e` "graphicx". Ce ne sono diversi  %
%   altri da cui scegliere.                           %
%                                                     %
%   Esempio di uso: avendo un file di nome            %
%   figura1.eps questa si inserisce nella tesi        %
%   col comando                                       %
%                                                     %
%        \begin{figure}[ht]                           %
%        \begin{center}                               %
%        \includegraphics{figura1.eps}                %
%        \caption[nome breve]{nome lungo}             %
%        \label{etichetta}                            %
%        \end{center}                                 %
%        \end{figure}                                 %
%                                                     %
%   Il "nome breve" e` quello che apparira`           %
%   nell'indice delle figure ed e' opzionale.         %
%   Il "nome lungo" e' quello che appare              %
%   sotto la figura.                                  %
%   (Ci sono opzioni per scalare, spostare, ruotare   %
%   le figure).                                       %
%   Con \graphicspath{{./figure/}} si dice            %
%   al LaTeX di cercare le figure nella cartella      %
%   "figure" situata allo stesso livello di           %
%   questo documento                                  %
%                                                     %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   %  Esempi di macro definite dall'utente.  %
   %  Le prime definiscono dei comandi per   %
   %  scrivere i caratteri speciali per      %
   %  gli insiemi numerici fondamentali      %
   %  (naturali, interi, razionali, reali,   %
   %  complessi                              %
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}

   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   %  Delle macro che definiscono operatori   %
   %  non predefiniti in LaTeX. Ogni utente   %
   %  aggiunge quelle che servono. Questi     %
   %  sono solo esempi arbitrari.             %
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\DeclareMathOperator{\traccia}{tr}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sen}{sen}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arcsen}{arcsen}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\maxlim}{max\,lim}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\minlim}{min\,lim}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\deepinf}{\phantom{\makebox[0pt]{p}}inf}



% Ridefiniamo la riga di testa delle pagine:
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}

               %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
               %  Informazioni generali sulla Tesi  %
               %    da usare nell'intestazione      %
               %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

  \titolo{La mia tesi\\ di Matematica}
  \laureanda{Giovanna Tesista}
% \laureando{Giovanni Tesista}
  \annoaccademico{2013-2014}
% \facolta{Scienze Matematiche, Fisiche e Naturali} % (default)
%  \corsodilaurea{Informatica} % per la laurea vecchio ordinamento
\corsodilaureatriennalein{Matematica}
% \corsodilaureaspecialisticain{Informatica}
% \corsodilaureamagistralein{Matematica}
  \relatore[Prof.]{Tal dei Tali}
%  \relatoreDue[Prof.]{Secondo relatore}
% \correlatore{Talaltro dei Tali}
% \correlatoreDue{Secondo Correlatore}
  \dedica{Ai miei genitori\\
    per non avermi tagliato i viveri} % (facoltativo)

% Per l'ipertesto:
 \usepackage{hyperref} % gia' caricato da uniudtesi
\hypersetup{
  % pdfpagelayout=SinglePage, % default
  % pdfpagemode=UseOutlines, % default
  bookmarksopen, % default
  bookmarksopenlevel=2, % default;
  pdftitle={La mia Tesi},
  pdfauthor={Giovanna Tesista},
  pdfsubject={Modello di Tesi di Laurea},
  pdfkeywords={tesi laurea LaTeX}} % Queste informazioni non vengono stampate, ma sono conservate nel documento pdf. Sono consultabili col menu "File>Document Properites>Description". Vengono buone a scopi archivistici.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


   %%%                                    %        %%    %%
  %   %                                   %         %     %
  %      %%%  % %%  %%%%   %%%         %%%%  %%%    %     %    %%%%
  %     %   % %%  % %   % %   %       %   % %   %   %     %   %   %
  %     %   % %     %   % %   %       %   % %%%%%   %     %   %   %
  %   % %   % %     %   % %   %       %   % %       %     %   %  %%
   %%%   %%%  %     %%%%   %%%         %%%%  %%%%  %%%   %%%   %% %
                    %
                    %


                          %%%%%               %
                            %
                            %    %%%   %%%%  %%
                            %   %   % %       %
                            %   %%%%%  %%%    %
                            %   %         %   %
                            %    %%%% %%%%   %%%


 \begin{document}

         %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
         %            Intestazione                       %
         %                                               %
         % Per l'intestazione completa bisogna           %
         % essersi procurati il file "polloPallido.eps". %
         %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\frontmatter
\maketitle
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  %   Si puo` scegliere fra scrivere tutta la tesi in un    %
  %   solo file, oppure distribuire ogni capitolo in un     %
  %   file a parte. Qui si e` scelto tenere separati i      %
  %   vari capitoli, che vengono caricati con \include      %
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}}%consigliato per migliorare i numeri di equazione nell'introduzione
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}%consigliato per migliorare i numeri di equazione nell'introduzione


\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\mainmatter

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thechapter.\arabic{equation}}%si torna alle formule numerate come da default
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}%si torna alle sezioni numerate come da default

\input{introduzione}

\input{capitolo1}

\input{capitolo2}


\backmatter

\input{biblio}


\end{document}
```

What is wrong here?

P.s: thesis in italian

Comment: Hello there, welcome to the site :) I think we may need to see the first chapter that you're `\input`ing in order to help you, as I don't think you've provided the actual code that's giving problems. Have a look at this page for more help on how to construct a Minimal Working Example (MWE): [link](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: The uniudtesi package is here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Jazzinghen/SPAM-and-BROFist--A-Love-Story/master/Official/uniudtesi.sty

Comment: Does one of your files contain the $ character? If that is the case, please include this file also. Maybe it requires escaping.

Comment: See `Missing $ inserted. ...na patologia unicamente femminile, ma puÃ²` (first line of your errors): The last, perhaps the last two characters are not compatible with `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}`, and there are more strange characters like this in the following lines. You should mask such characters, or use another input encoding. Now, these characters are somehow interpreted as control/active characters, I guess. That's why you get errors about missing `$` (which turns math mode on/off) and extra `}` (which marks the end of a  group).

Comment: Just copy the text from Word into your text editor, compile the document, and if LaTeX throws an error, go to that line, look for a weird character, and search/delete this character in the complete text. There are probably various weird characters, so you have to repeat this procedure. Take notes what characters you have deleted, and when your text compiles without errors, you can look for a way to mask these characters LaTeX-style.

Comment: I solved these problems replacing "è", "ò", "ù", "à", "ì", with `\`e`, `\`o` and so on. I can't understand why these problems doesn't happen in the introduction, where there are "è", "ò" and so on. 
introduction.tex begins with `\chapter*{Introduzione} \pagenumbering{roman}`while capitolo1.tex begins with `\chapter{} \pagenumbering{arabic}`. There aren't any tables, images or equations for now. Just text (unformatted).  Now that I know that, I will use "\`e", "\`o" etc, but it was easier if I could copy from Word.

Comment: You can certainly use è, etc. in LaTeX, you just have to set up the encodings correctly, but you need to let us  help you by providing a proper MWE. Currently you seem to be using latin1 encoding, you should try UTF8 encoding if your editor is using UTF8

Comment: I've replaced `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` with `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`and it gave me error. In case you're asking, yes I setted UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the log and the comments below your question, you really should switch all the *.tex files you'd like to compile from latin-1 to utf-8.

There are two steps necessary:

1. The files (*.tex) themeselves are encoded. You need to "recode" them. But often the current enconding of the files isn't not entirely clear. The recoding of files has been discussed e.g. here: [How do I change the encoding of my files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19427/4736) , https://stackoverflow.com/q/64860 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/2014069 .
2. The second step is replacing `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` with `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, but maybe your editor can do both for you in one step, like emacs does.