# A way to change the encoding of a .tex file

Tags: input-encodings, font-encodings

Sometimes, when the contents of a .tex is copied from .docx file, its own encoding might not fit your expectation and cause problems as you compiling it. One way to convert the file to the encoding you want is to use WinEdt: when "save as" a different file, you can have several choices.

Comment: utf-8 isn't a font encoding, it is the encoding of the tex file source, as written by the editor, If you have copied text using the windows clipboard  it will (usually) be pasted using the encoding of the file that you are pasting to, so it doesn't matter what encoding was used in the source (but most likely they are both utf-8 anyway)

Comment: If your editor is not capable of dealing with your encoding, delete it and install a better one.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It is a fact that when my friend trying to compile my .tex file with her WinEdt, she always gets a warning saying that "Some characters were lost while converting from UNICODE to CP 0.

Comment: so if some characters are lost then you are processing different files so it is not surprising that the output is different and miktex/texlive and package differences are not relevant. Your friend should just configure winedt to use utf8 encoding not a legacy code page on the file.

Comment: You get this message from winedt if winedt thinks that the file should be ascii or ansi. If the status line of your friend says "ACP" for this file she should use file->convert to utf8 to convert it (and make a backup first -- such conversions can sometimes gives the wrong result if you have curious files).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question but a kind of statement or how-to or blog. So is cannot be answered. We could only discuss it, but this is not a discussion forum.

Comment: If you like to show, how to change the encoding of a file using WinEdt, please do it as an answer, e.g., to [How do I change the encoding of my files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19427/how-do-i-change-the-encoding-of-my-files)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the encoding of my files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19427/how-do-i-change-the-encoding-of-my-files)