# Problem with `tabular`

Tags: tables

With the following codes

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}


\begin{document}


\section*{Work Experience}
  \begin{tabular}{r|p{13cm}}
 \textsc{Sebt.2011-Now}
 & Teaching Assistant, Department of Mathematics,
  University of California, Santa Barbara.\\
  & Delivered courses: ......\\
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
  \textsc{Feb.2011-May 2011}
  & Substitute teacher at ....%\\
 \end{tabular}



 \end{document}
```

I get

[image]

> Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column `p{13cm}` is too wide and produces an Overfull hbox.

I suggest to use `tabularx` with an `X` column type.

Moreover, instead of writing `\textsc{...}` in every cell of the first column, you can create a new colum type this way `\newcolumntype{R}{>{\scshape}r}` with `array` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\scshape}r}
\begin{document}
\section*{Work Experience}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{R|X}
 Sebt.2011-Now
 & Teaching Assistant, Department of Mathematics,
  University of California, Santa Barbara.\\
  & Delivered courses: ......\\
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
 Feb.2011-May 2011
  & Substitute teacher at ....%\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please if I add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and I hope to write for example `Gabès` it doen't compilate. However with `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` it complilates well. Where is the problem? Thank you.

Comment: @Schüler It depends on the input encoding of your editor, see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19427/how-do-i-change-the-encoding-of-my-files